# How to replace certain cells value in a dataframe (R)

Tags: r

I would like to know why the following piece of code is not working:

```
f <- function(){
  for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    for(j in 1:ncol(df)){
      if(df[i,j] == ""){
        df[i,j] <- 0
      }
    }
  }
}

f()
## Error in if (df[i, j] == "") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I found many different ways how to do exactly the same just by one command, however, I would like to know how to proceed it this way. The error apparently occurs while evaluating the condition. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using a `for` loop, we can directly apply `replace` to change the elements that are blanks (`""`) to 0

```
replace(df, df=="", 0)
```

---

Or use `lapply` with `replace`

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) replace(x, x=="", 0))
```

---

Based on a reproducible example the OP's code would work fine

```
set.seed(24)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c("", 1:4), 5*4, replace=TRUE), 
                ncol=5), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
f <- function(){
 for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
   for(j in 1:ncol(df)){
   if(df[i,j] == ""){
     df[i,j] <- 0
   }
  }
 }
df
}

f()
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1  1  3  4  3  0
#2  1  4  1  3  0
#3  3  1  3  1  2
#4  2  3  1  4  0
```

Now, consider another dataset with missing values i.e. NA,

```
set.seed(32)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c("", 1:4, NA), 5*4, replace=TRUE), 
      ncol=5), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
f()
#Error in if (df[i, j] == "") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

So, consider to first replace the `NA` to something else or change the condition in the function to

```
 if(df[i,j]== "" & !is.na(df[i,j])
```

Applying the function again with the changes

```
f()
#  V1   V2 V3 V4   V5
#1  3    0  4  3    4
#2  3 <NA>  2  4    2
#3  4    4  3  1    3
#4  4 <NA>  1  4 <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks, I found this solution in some other post but I still would like to know why my code is not working as it can be helpful next time.

Comment: @New2coding  Based on an example created, your code is working fine (just had to create the return statement)  Check the `str(df)` and you will find the clue

Comment: FID;OBJECTID;GRID_ID;Score_valu;OID_;OBJECTID_1;Cnt_OBJECT;Ave_Area;Ave_ED;Sum_Score
0;37202;FT-57;0,000000000000000;0;37202;1;37,650114709999997;74,269360453199994;75,300229419999994
1;37203;FU-57;0,000000000000000;1;37203;2;118,482169738000000;173,157945197000000;552,134314209999960
2;37204;FV-57;0,000000000000000;2;37204;3;56,471721166700000;103,444439065000000;1386,175033080000000
3;37205;FW-57;0,000000000000000;;;;;;

Comment: this is a part of the data my code failed at

Comment: @New2coding  Based on the error, I think you may have NA elements.  Please check my updated post

Comment: There are some strings NA, perhaps, that was the reason of the error message. Thanks for your help.